# Concept about absolutely continuous.

Tags: probability

Suppose $\nu$ and $\mu$ are 2 measure in $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$:

What's the difference between:

(1)$\nu\ll \mu$

(2)$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,\forall A\in\mathcal F\rm{s.t.}\mu(A)<\delta,\rm{ we have}\quad \nu(A)<\epsilon$

(2)$\Rightarrow$(1):

select $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n},\forall A\in\mathcal F\rm{s.t.}\mu(A)=0,\rm{ we have}\quad \nu(A)<\frac{1}{n}$ Let n$\to\infty$

BUT is there any counterexample for (1)$\Rightarrow$(2)?

Comment: $\mu=\text{Lebesgue-measure}$, $\nu =\infty\cdot \mu$ with the understanding that $\infty \cdot 0=0$. If $\nu$ is a finite measure, then (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Comment: @PhoemueX ,If $\nu $ is fintie,use Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\nu$ is finite and (2) does not hold. Then there is $\varepsilon >0$ such that for each $n$, there is a set $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n) < 1/2^n$ but $\nu(A_n)\geq \varepsilon$.

Define

$$N := \bigcap_n \bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m$$

It is easy to see $\mu(N)=0$. Furthermore (because $\nu$ is a finite measure),

$$
\nu(N) = \lim_n \nu(\bigcup_{m\geq n} A_m) \geq \varepsilon,
$$

so that (1) does not hold.